# JS: best way to keep track of unique key/value pairings?

Tags: javascript

I am iterating through objects of font data and want to push or add their postscript name and style as a key/value pair. The postscript name will *always* be the regular version of the postscript so I need to keep track of the style with it. For example, I want my data structure to look like:

```
[
   { "Arial-MT", "Bold" },
   { "Arial-MT", "Regular"}
]
```

While iterating though, if I come across another `postscript_name` that is `Arial-MT` and style of either `Bold` or `Regular`, I don't want to add it to my data object.  What is the cleanest approach to this?

Comment: It's clear to me what you mean. It sounds like you want to ignore names if you have come across them already? For storing key value pairs you can either use an object or a `Map`.

Comment: The data structure you posted as an example isn't valid. This would need to be an array of objects.

Comment: @FelixKling yes but only ignore them if both the key and value are already a pair

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an object containing `Sets` of strings.

```
const styles = {
    "Ariel-MT": new Set(["Bold", "Regular"])
};

postscript_data.forEach(([postscript_name, postscript_style]) => {
    if (styles[postscript_name]) {
        styles[postscript_name].add(postscript_style);
    } else {
        style[postscript_name] = new Set([postscript_style])
    }
});
```

Comment: oh I like this approach a lot.  I didn't to use a `Set` for the value.  Thanks for this idea.

Comment: WOW didn't know before that a value of an object could be a `Set`

Comment: The value of a property can be anything.

Answer (score 0):

I've correct the data structure you provide as *an array of objects*:

```js
const data = [
   { "Arial-MT": "Bold" },
   { "Arial-MT": "Regular"},
   { "Arial-MT": "Bold" },
   { "Arial-MT": "Regular"},
];
let visited = [];
let result = [];
for(const obj of data){
  const [k,v] = Object.entries(obj)[0];
  if(!visited.includes(`${k}_${v}`)){
      const new_obj = {}
      new_obj[k] = v;
      result.push(new_obj);
    visited.push(`${k}_${v}`);
  }
}
console.log(result)
```